# Finding planar expression

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d, solid-geometry

CONTEXT: First year university mathematics course question

Given an equation for displacement in metres is $R(x,y,z)=\frac{25z^2+30}{x^2+y^2}+40$, where $(x,y,z)$ represents coordinates in three-dimensional space and a point $M(3,1,2)$, find an expression for the surface which has the same displacement as M.

I found the displacement at M after substituting it into the equation to be $53$ metres, but am unsure of where to go from here.

Does this mean I let $R(x,y,z)=53$ which simplifies to $0=\frac{25z^2+30}{x^2+y^2}-13$, and then just set the LHS to be $R_1(x,y,z)$ so I have $R_1(x,y,z)=\frac{25z^2+30}{x^2+y^2}-13$? Then, my expression for the surface is $\frac{25z^2+30}{x^2+y^2}-13$. I have a feeling this is incorrect but don't know how to trouble shoot it.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The equation should be $\frac{25z^2+30}{x^2+y^2}-13 = 0$

Comment: @ab123 The question asks for an expression so wouldn't answering with an equation be incorrect? But then it also feels wrong to just disregard a side of an equation to satisfy this.